# How to keep a new jewelry box that’s covered with a white pebbled leather material clean

Tags: cleaning, home, dust

I have an older house that no matter how much I clean, manufactures dust. I want to put my new jewelry box on my dresser but I know with it being white and fake leather covered, it’s going to be horrid quickly. Anyone know of a protectant I could use or buy that might keep it nice?  It’s been in the box it came in for 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

There are many kinds of materials and treatments for materials that might sound appealing and a good idea for one or more reasons.
If you treat the box, you might be doing more harm than if you did nothing more than dust it from time to time as normal.

There are several different but similar faux leather [leatherette, vinyl, plastic, etc.] finishes that might yellow over time. Light is probably more to blame for changes to colour than dust. You'll want to avoid direct strong natural light. Over time, each face of the box will be a different tint. Even worse is exposure to smoke and city air pollution.

In short: Unbox the jewelry case. Avoid trying to second-guess what may happen over time with an unknown "prevention" attempt.

In a few years, you might want to treat it with some stuff to rejuvenate the finish. There are a number of products with clever names such as "Re-Nu-Zit™ miracle restorer" [I made that one up]. When you do, you'll probably also change the finish which will have a "patina" from the time it has been on display and enjoyed in use.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZTXPJ6) spray on both leather and non-leather shoes. It would probably help with your jewelry box as well. Test it on the back or somewhere not visible before spraying the whole box, though. The product I linked to is a boot protector, but I have a suede protector from the same brand that works equally well, so choose whichever of that brand's product seems to most closely fit your needs.